# how to POST multipart list of JSON/xml files using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

In python2.7 I use `requests` to communicate with a REST endpoint. I can upload single JSON and xml objects to it.
To speed things up I want to upload multiple json objects using multipart.

I have a curl command that show how it can be done and this works.
I need to translate that in a python requests POST command.

WORKING curl POST:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST --data-binary \@sample-body \
     -i -H "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" \
     "http://localhost:8058/v1/resources/sight-ingest?rs:transform=aireco-transform&rs:title=file1.xml&rs:title=file2.xml&rs:title=file3.xml"
```

Things to note:
I need to send custom parameter list including a list of 'title' parameters, cannot do that by passing a dict? but we can potentially work around this.

my python trail:

```
import requests
files = {'file1': ('foo.txt', 'foo\ncontents\n','text/plain'), 
          'file2': ('bar.txt', 'bar contents', 'text/plain'),
          'file3': ('baz.txt', 'baz contents', 'text/plain')}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed','Content-Disposition': 'attachment','boundary': 'GRENS'}
params={'title':'file1','title':'file2','title':'file2'}
r = requests.Request('POST', 'http://example.com', files=files , headers=headers, params=params)
print r.prepare().url
print r.prepare().headers
print r.prepare().body
```

Gives me:

```
http://example.com/?title=file2
{'boundary': 'GRENS', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed', 'Content-Length': '471', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'}
--7f18a6c1b09f42009228f600b0af35fd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file3"; filename="baz.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

baz contents
--7f18a6c1b09f42009228f600b0af35fd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="bar.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

bar contents
--7f18a6c1b09f42009228f600b0af35fd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

foo
contents

--7f18a6c1b09f42009228f600b0af35fd--
```

### Questions:

- Seems the stuff in the header is not used in the body?
- Can i set my own boundary? 'GRENS' is not used in the body?
- Can I pass a list of title parameters (with same key) as in curl example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use a dictionary, use a list of `(key, value)` tuples for your query parameters:

```
params = [('title', 'file1'), ('title', 'file2'), ('title', 'file3')]
```

otherwise you'll end up with just the one key.

You should *not* set the `Content-Type` header; `requests` will set that correctly for you when you use the `files` parameter; that way the correct boundary will also be included. You should never set the boundary directly yourself, really:

```
params = [('title', 'file1'), ('title', 'file2'), ('title', 'file3')]
r = requests.post('http://example.com', 
                  files=files, headers=headers, params=params)
```

You can set headers **per file part** by adding a 4th element to the per-file tuple for extra headers, but in your case, you should not try to set the `Content-Disposition` header yourself; it'll be overwritten anyway.

Introspecting a prepared request object then gives you:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> files = {'file1': ('foo.txt', 'foo\ncontents\n','text/plain'), 
...           'file2': ('bar.txt', 'bar contents', 'text/plain'),
...           'file3': ('baz.txt', 'baz contents', 'text/plain')}
>>> headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'}
>>> params = [('title', 'file1'), ('title', 'file2'), ('title', 'file3')]
>>> r = requests.Request('POST', 'http://example.com',
...                      files=files, headers=headers, params=params)
>>> prepared = r.prepare()
>>> prepared.url
'http://example.com/?title=file1&title=file2&title=file3'
>>> pprint(dict(prepared.headers))
{'Content-Disposition': 'attachment',
 'Content-Length': '471',
 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=7312ccd96db94419bf1d97f2c54bbad1'}
>>> print prepared.body
--7312ccd96db94419bf1d97f2c54bbad1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file3"; filename="baz.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

baz contents
--7312ccd96db94419bf1d97f2c54bbad1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="bar.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

bar contents
--7312ccd96db94419bf1d97f2c54bbad1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

foo
contents

--7312ccd96db94419bf1d97f2c54bbad1--
```

If you absolutely must have `multipart/mixed` and not `multipart/form-data`, you'll have to build the POST body yourself and set the headers from that. The included [`urllib3` tools](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) should be able to do this for you:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField
from requests.packages.urllib3.filepost import encode_multipart_formdata

fields = []    
for name, (filename, contents, mimetype) in files.items():
    rf = RequestField(name=name, data=contents,
                      filename=filename)
    rf.make_multipart(content_disposition='attachment', content_type=mimetype)
    fields.append(rf)

post_body, content_type = encode_multipart_formdata(fields)
content_type = ''.join(('multipart/mixed',) + content_type.partition(';')[1:])

headers = {'Content-Type': content_type}
requests.post('http://example.com', data=post_body, headers=headers, params=params)
```

or you could use the [`email` package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html) to do the same:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

body = MIMEMultipart()
for name, (filename, contents, mimetype) in files.items():
    part = MIMEText(contents, _subtype=mimetype.partition('/')[-1], _charset='utf8')
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    body.attach(part)

post_body = body.as_string().partition('\n\n')[-1]
content_type = body['content-type']

headers = {'Content-Type': content_type}
requests.post('http://example.com', data=post_body, headers=headers, params=params)
```

but take into account that this method expects you to set a character set (I assumed UTF-8 for JSON and XML) and that it'll more than likely use Base64 encoding for the contents:

```
>>> body = MIMEMultipart()
>>> for name, (filename, contents, mimetype) in files.items():
...     part = MIMEText(contents, _subtype=mimetype.partition('/')[-1], _charset='utf8')
...     part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
...     body.attach(part)
... 
>>> post_body = body.as_string().partition('\n\n')[-1]
>>> content_type = body['content-type']
>>> print post_body
--===============1364782689914852112==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="baz.txt"

YmF6IGNvbnRlbnRz

--===============1364782689914852112==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="bar.txt"

YmFyIGNvbnRlbnRz

--===============1364782689914852112==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.txt"

Zm9vCmNvbnRlbnRzCg==

--===============1364782689914852112==--

>>> print content_type
multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1364782689914852112=="
```

Comment: thank you so far, the parameter stuff works, now what if my server NEEDS Content-type multipart/fixed and cannot handle multipart/form-data ? is there a way to force the contenttype and still have the boundary

Comment: @HugoKoopmans: you'd have to produce the POST body yourself; `requests` can only produce `multipart/form-data` for you. The `urllib2` tools are flexible enough though; I've updated my answer to produce such an output.

Comment: thx again for quick help, seems I have an issue importing the Requestfield ...     from requests.packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField
ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3.fields I had earlier problems with requests installed locaally any suggestion on this?

Comment: @HugoKoopmans: reinstall? What version of requests have you got? How was it installed?