# writing multiple documents to Marklogic REST extension using multipart/form-data

Tags: marklogic

I have seen documententaion here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_54649

It starts with " To write multiple documents in a single request, send a POST request to the /v1/documents service with a URL of the following form and set the Content-Type header to multipart/mixed. "

Problem is I use python Requests that, by default, uses content-type multipart/form-data which I cannot change see [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299889/how-to-post-multipart-list-of-json-xml-files-using-python-requests)

So my question: can I set up Marklogic REST extension so it uses multipart/form-data instead of multipart/mixed

Answer (score 1):

[XQRS](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs) can accept file uploads via [multipart/form-data](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/form-file-uploads) requests no sweat, including multiple uploads of course. It's also a great and simple way of making RESTful Web Services on MarkLogic. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the python SO question you are referring to, there are libraries that should allow you to compose a true multipart/mixed request to use against `/v1/documents`.

Having said that, I think it should be real easy to support multipart/form-data from anywhere inside MarkLogic. It is supported natively, and from the looks of it REST extensions can work with them too.

I ran a quick test with an HTML upload form that uses `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Inside the form you can use input field of type `file`. Regarding REST extensions, just make sure you prefix any input field name with `rs:` as required for custom params to REST extensions. And if you want to insert the files into the database, you will need to annotate the REST extension `post` function with `%rapi:transaction-mode("update")` to make sure it runs in update mode.

You'll have to translate the above to Python of course, but that shouldn't be difficult.

HTH!