# Python requests content does not contain response

Tags: python, http-post, httpresponse

I am trying to use python `requests` module to get the melting temperature of some query DNA sequence from [this](http://sg.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer) website by clicking analyze. I am using the following code.

```
import requests

referer = "http://sg.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer"
data = {"settings":{"Sequence":"GGGGGGGAAAAAAGGGGGG","NaConc":50,"MgConc":0,"DNTPsConc":0,"OligoConc":0.25,"NucleotideType":"DNA"}}

r = requests.post(referer, params=data)
print r.content
```

However the "MELT TEMP" and all other fields are blank in the `r.content` of the response. This is despite the "response" tab under the name "analyze" in Chrome's inspect having the content I am after.

See the inspected element here.

[image: Chrome inspect element]

If I navigate the the Response tab of the above image, I find the following which contains exactly the information I am after.

```
{"Sequence":"GGG GGG GAA AAA AGG GGG G","NaConc":50,"MgConc":0,"dNTPsConc":0,"Complement":"CCC CCC TTT TTT CCC CCC C","Length":19,"GCContent":68.4,"MeltTemp":61.4,"MolecularWeight":6097,"ExtCoefficient":205900,"NmoleOD":4.86,"UgOD":29.61,"NucleotideType":"DNA","OligoConc":0.25,"HasErrors":false,"HasModelErrors":false,"ModelErrors":null,"MinMeltTemp":0,"MaxMeltTemp":0,"Mods":[{"ExtensionData":{},"IntProductId":1012,"ProductName":"DNA","ProductType":0,"PublishedProductNbr":1012,"ShortName":"","TotalProductCount":19}],"Errors":[]}
```

Comment: This particular query should give a "MELT TEMP" of 61.4 degrees.

Comment: `requests.post(...` **is not** a _**click**_. There is some `javascript` that respond upon the click.

Comment: Good point! I have updated above. There only appears to be one name (`analyze`) that is a `post` request that gives the relevant information. Where might I find/request the javascript for the click?

Comment: Your Inspect Image shows _**Content-Type: application/json**_, try `r = requests.post(referer, json=data)`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `json=data` and `json=json.dumps(data)` but no luck. I get the same content returned each time which is a lot of HTML describing the page with blank fields where the data should be. I don't get a short description like the response tab of Chrome's inspect.

Comment: I get the same HTML in `r.content` response whether I send any `data` or not.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Where might I find/request the javascript for the click?

1. Find in Page Source the Relevant `javascript function`  from the `button Analyze`

   ```
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block"
       id="analyze-button"
       style="width:150px;"
       data-bind="click: useTool.bind($data, 'analyze') "
       onclick="TrackPageEvent('Analyze button')">
       Analyze
   </button>
   ```
2. Find the Relevant Function `click: useTool` in Page Source Inside '<script>...</script>`.

   ```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
   for script in soup.find_all("script"):     
       for f in ['useTool', 'TrackPageEvent']:
           if script.find(f):
               print('MATCH({}) in {}'.format(f, script))
   ```

   There is **NO** match!
3. Find all '<script src=...></script>`

   ```
   for script in soup.find_all("script"):     
       src = script.get('src')
       if src:
           print('{}'.format(src))
   ```

   > **Output**:
   >   /site/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js
   >   /site/Scripts/amplify/amplify.core.min.js
   >   /site/Scripts/amplify/amplify.store.min.js
   >   /site/scripts/idtdna/Common/RequireJSConfig.js?v=1
   >   /bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
   >   /JScripts/idtdna-searchcloudV6.js?v=2
   >   /JScripts/knockout-3.4.0.js
   >   /JScripts/uAnalyticsLoad2.js?v=2
   >   /JScripts/IDTHeader.js?v=11
   >   /calc/Scripts/json2.min.js
   >   /calc/Areas/Analyzer/Scripts/Analyzer3.js?v=5

   One of the Script starting with **/calc** are likely the Relevant Script.
4. Download `/calc/Areas/Analyzer/Scripts/Analyzer3.js?v=5` and search for the relevant Function `useTool`. 
   Found at Line 495:

   ```
   self.useTool = function (tool) {
       ...
       var url = '/calc/analyzer/home/';
       var postData = self.analyzePostData();
       ...
           case 'analyze':
               url += 'analyze';
       ...
       $.ajax({
               url: url,
               data: JSON.stringify(postData),
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
   ```
5. Rebuild the `$.ajax(...` Request using `requests`.
   The `url = /calc/analyzer/home/analyze` is Different from yours.
   This may be the Reason your Request are not Recognized!
   But using this `url` Results in: *Page Not Found*

   The `contentType: 'application/json` is not supported from `requests` by Default.
   Couldn't Answer this yet.
   Relevant SO Answer: [how to POST multipart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26300042/7414759)